# CWL file: label in the #2 if optional #1 not given

Tags: texstudio

I want to include the following in the CWL file:

```
\xlabel[label]{nonlabel}#l
\xlabel{label}#l
```

because \xlabel[2][]{...} works so that the if the first (optional) argument is given, it serves as a label, otherwise the second argument serves as a label.

However, that .cwl code does not work. In all cases only the optional argument (if any) is added on the label list. I guess that the cwl file is only processed up to the first line when \xlabel is used, even if there is no optional argument.

How can I tell TeXstudio that without the optional argument, the only argument serves as a label?

Now I use this: `\xlabel[label]{label}#l`. Unfortunately, therefore, my label list holds also non-labels.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not supported in TeXstudio. You can open an issue in https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues to get help from the maintainers of TeXstudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution seems to be to redefine \xlabel so that it always works this way:

```
\xlabel[nonlabel]{label}#l
```

Other solutions would require massive rewriting of TeXstudio, and it seems that there is no reason why the label could not be the obligatory argument in any similar commands.
https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1135